# Create Dialog Box/pop up windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

have such code

```
bool b = EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Test",
 "Reset or continue?", "Reset", "Continue");
if (b)
{
    ResetGame();
}
```

but it works only in Editor and not in Game. How to replace the EditorUtility.DisplayDialog with something that works for game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Unity class that includes the word "Editor" or came from the `UnityEditor` namespace means that the `class` is designed to used in the Editor **only** and will **only** work in the Editor. So `EditorUtility` is for Unity Editor **only**.

You need to implement your own Modal Window and to be able to this, you must **understand** basic Unity UI such as creating buttons, panels, texts. So [learn](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) the Unity **basic** UI first. All you need to do is to put the UI Objects in a panel then acivate/deactivate them when needed.

For example, this is your dialogue panle:

```
public GameObject dialoguePanel;
```

to show a dialogue of the UI Panel

```
dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
```

To hide it:

```
dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
```

You can subscribe to the dialogue's button or UI controls events dynamically with `onClick.AddListener`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) post for more information on how to subscribe to UI events.

If you still can't implement your **Modal Window**, then follow the **tutorials** below as that's exactly what you are looking for.

Unity Tutorial for a generic modal Window:

[MAKING A GENERIC MODAL WINDOW Part 1](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window)

[MAKING A GENERIC MODAL WINDOW Part 2](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window-pt2)

[MAKING A GENERIC MODAL WINDOW Part 3](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/modal-window-pt3)

Comment: how to make your own window ?

Comment: @user3153616 You can call it a dialog but it can be called a modal window... It becomes a Modal window when you have a dialog with background picture and can be moved around if you want it to. The tutorials 1 to 3 will show you how.