# Getting text from an input field only works after focus changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a Pause menu for a simple game i'm making. In that pause menu there is a field to enter your username. I'm attempting to check that a username has been entered before the user is allowed to close the pause menu. However both the `input.text` and `input.TextComponent.text` values are only changed to the typed username when focus is changed away from the input field.

My code is as follows:

```
public InputField input;
if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty (input.text)) || (input.text == "Enter Username")){
    input.textComponent.color = Color.red;
    input.text = "Enter Username";
} else {
    input.textComponent.color = Color.black;

    //hide pause menu and resume game
    canvas.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

This code only works when the user clicks away from the input field box before attempting to close the pause menu. How can I get the text entered as its entered?

I've tried adding `GUI.focusControl("")` and `GUI.focusControl(null)` before the if statement but this doesn't work either.

Edit :

I've confirmed that the second parameter of the `if` statement is working. The menu doesn't close if the entered text is "Enter Username", so i know im checking the text variable correctly. I just dont understand why the if statement returns true if you enter in anything else? I must be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `GUI.focusControl("")` and `GUI.focusControl(null)` have nothing to do with the Unity's new UI system(uGUI). They are made to work with IMGUI.

If you want to focus on `InputField` you can use the code below:

```
public InputField input;
input.ActivateInputField();
input.Select();
```

To stop the focus

```
input.DeactivateInputField();
```

Do **not** try to poll `InputField.text`. That's not how use it. You do have two options in this case:

**1**.Subscribe to the `InputField` `onEndEdit` event.

When the player is done typing and clicks Enter/Return or away, this function will be called. You can then check/compare for the username there.
Check **#3** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) post.

**2**.Add a Button that says "check" or "submit". When user is done typing, they will have to click that Button. Subscribe to the Buttons onClick event. When the `Button` is clicked you then check/compare for the username there. Check **#2** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) post.

If you find another tricky way to do this, it will work but not on Android device. You will end up rewriting the code again.