# CrossFadeAlpha not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a canvas for UI, with an image the same size of the canvas. The image has an `rgba` of `0,0,0,0` , making it invisible (because the `a` is `0`). I want to have the image fade into black from a script. The script is called by the `button` in the menu when it is clicked. Here is the code I am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NavigationC : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool Starting = false;
    public Image screen;
    float fadeTime = 3f;

    void StartGame()
    {
        Starting = true;
        StartCoroutine(wait());
        screen.CrossFadeAlpha(1f, fadeTime, true);

    }
}
```

Picture of the image in inspector:
[image: Picture of the image in inspector]

By changing some values I can get it to work, but it is far from ideal and it should be solveable instead of using this workaround. Here is the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3M-S0EHwwNk

For some reason I can get it to work using either `255` or `255f`. I don't want to use such a workaround but I left these in the video to show my desired outcome (which is the fade).

Picture of the button which calls the function:
[image]

Comment: When people ask you to update your question with code, you're supposed to _edit_ it, not ask a new question. Also, questions are meant to be self-contained. If the video contains important information, then that clearly is not the case. I recommend reading [ask].

Comment: He asked me to create a new question. The video was also a request. The information is all in the question itself, it is just visualization.

Comment: I fully understand after the video. I will try to replicate that and let you know.

Comment: Did you ever realize that the `StartGame` function is not even being called anywhere? Nothing is calling it.....

Comment: It has to, because it does work with other values. But yeah, sorry, it is being called from the button in the UI, my mistake for not telling you.

Comment: That's fine. I am still correct. I think that you are calling the wrong function. You can't call `StartGame` like  that from the Button since it is not a `public` variable. It must be `public void StartGame(){...}` before it can be called from the Button from the Editor. Please, verify this.

Comment: Like you saw yourself, it does work when I just change the value to 255. It is not called in a script but by a component, I added a picture to the post. I had public at some point, otherwise I couldn't have added it, I guess I removed it in testing at some point. It still works, I can display a `Debug.Log` for example but I can't reselect it in the button, changed it to `public`. A small mistake, but not the one we're looking for.

Comment: That's the thing though. Mistakes like these can make the comment section long and it will make the problem look like something else. I suggest you set that back to a public function. If you want to use a private function for the `Button` then register it [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) through code instead of the Editor. This will save you or anyone on your team time in the future. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that this is with `CrossFadeAlpha`. The workaround is to get the current color, set the `Color.a` to `1` then set it back to `0` with  `CrossFadeAlpha(0f, 0f, true);`. After that, you can then call your `screen.CrossFadeAlpha(1, fadeTime, false);`
 function.

You wont see the effect of setting `Color.a` to `1` because you are setting it back to `0` with `screen.CrossFadeAlpha(0f, 0f, true);` in *the-same* frame.

This is the proper workaround and should fix this problem:

```
Color fixedColor = screen.color;
fixedColor.a = 1;
screen.color = fixedColor;
screen.CrossFadeAlpha(0f, 0f, true);

screen.CrossFadeAlpha(1, fadeTime, false);
```

---

You can also make it an extension method so that it can be used from any where in your project and on any UI component:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static void CrossFadeAlphaFixed(this Graphic img, float alpha, float duration, bool ignoreTimeScale)
    {
        //Make the alpha 1
        Color fixedColor = img.color;
        fixedColor.a = 1;
        img.color = fixedColor;

        //Set the 0 to zero then duration to 0
        img.CrossFadeAlpha(0f, 0f, true);

        //Finally perform CrossFadeAlpha
        img.CrossFadeAlpha(alpha, duration, ignoreTimeScale);
    }
}
```

**Usage** :

```
private bool Starting = false;
public Image screen;
float fadeTime = 3f;

public void StartGame()
{
    Starting = true;
    StartCoroutine(wait());
    screen.CrossFadeAlphaFixed(1, fadeTime, false);
}
```

---

I noticed that you have  `StartCoroutine(wait());` in your code. It looks like you simply want to wait until the fading is done then do something(load new scene). I suggest you roll your own fade function that takes a callback function with `Action`.

```
 public void StartGame()
 {
     Starting = true;

     CrossFadeAlphaWithCallBack(screen, 1f, fadeTime, delegate
      {
          Debug.Log("Done Fading");
          SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
      });
 }

 void CrossFadeAlphaWithCallBack(Image img, float alpha, float duration, System.Action action)
 {
     StartCoroutine(CrossFadeAlphaCOR(img, alpha, duration, action));
 }

 IEnumerator CrossFadeAlphaCOR(Image img, float alpha, float duration, System.Action action)
 {
     Color currentColor = img.color;

     Color visibleColor = img.color;
     visibleColor.a = alpha;


     float counter = 0;

     while (counter < duration)
     {
         counter += Time.deltaTime;
         img.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, visibleColor, counter / duration);
         yield return null;
     }

     //Done. Execute callback
     action.Invoke();
 }
```

---

Again, you can make it an extension method so that it can be used anywhere in your project.

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static void CrossFadeAlphaWithCallBack(this Image img, float alpha, float duration, System.Action action)
    {
        MonoBehaviour mnbhvr = img.GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>();
        mnbhvr.StartCoroutine(CrossFadeAlphaCOR(img, alpha, duration, action));
    }

    public static IEnumerator CrossFadeAlphaCOR(Image img, float alpha, float duration, System.Action action)
    {
        Color currentColor = img.color;

        Color visibleColor = img.color;
        visibleColor.a = alpha;


        float counter = 0;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            img.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, visibleColor, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }

        //Done. Execute callback
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
private bool Starting = false;
public Image screen;
float fadeTime = 3f;

public void StartGame()
{
    Starting = true;

    screen.CrossFadeAlphaWithCallBack(1f, fadeTime, delegate
    {
        Debug.Log("Done Fading");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Even though this is still a workaround and not a fix for the unknown problem/bug, thanks for your help it works.

Comment: Yeah it's a bug. That's better than using 255 to solve it. Remember that I made functions to do this without Unity's fade function. You should use them, especially the one with the callback function until Unity fixes that.

Comment: Yeah, I will. Thanks for your help and patience.