# A simple touch equivalent for onMouseDrag in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm a bit surprised that there is no optional auto-conversion of basic touch actions to mouse. Well, at least none that I've found after 2 hours searching.. Anyways.. I have the following script to drag a 2D sprite:

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if (dragEnabled) { 
        Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, (transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z)));
        point.z = transform.position.z;
        transform.position = point;
    }
}
```

Pretty straighforward..
But now I need to make this work for touch, but every solution I found are either from 2011, fail to work and/or are dozens of lines long..

Is there a simple way to "convert" this to mobile, or, even better, make one solution that works for both cases?

Comment: See my question in here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/6786634  I think this is already have an answer.

Comment: This is for UI right? I'm looking to drag non-UI sprites

Comment: The new UI API is meant to work on both mobile and desktop. See the the post comment it described in there and the answer have NON UI OBJECT too.

Answer (score 2):

As @DennisLiu said: if you look to the end of [@Programmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/6786634), you'll find the way to do it with 3D objects (or simply non-UI objects). The easiest way to achieve what you're looking for is using the [**EventSystem**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) component with a **PhysicRaycaster** (same as the default **GraphicRaycaster** used for UI raycasting but for 3D objects):

- Add a **PhysicRaycaster** to your *MainCamera* object (this ones requires a **Camera**)
- Add an **EventSystem** on the object you want
- Add an **InputModule** (can be **Standalone** or **Touch** one in your case) on the same object as the **EventSystem** component

Then you simply have to subscribe to events as @Programmer explained.
You can fin the list of the supported events [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SupportedEvents.html).