# How can I make a UI display on screen when clicking on a game object in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a scene where when you click on an object (like a hotspot) a window pops up on the screen like in the screenshot. I got this to work using GUI textures however once the pop up displays it stays on the screen. Is there a way for me to click the texture and make it disappear?

Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict
private var guiShow : boolean = false;
var riddle : Texture;

function OnMouseDown () {
    guiShow = true;
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(guiShow == true)
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(Screen.width / 4.5, Screen.height / 4, 1024, 512), riddle);
    }
}
```

[image: GUI Texture Displaying]

Comment: You are using the old IMGUI. I suggest you watch Unity's tutorial for [UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui). Once you understand how to create UI controls, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api/41392130#41392130) is how to detect click on UI components or GameObjects.

Comment: Please post your code as text, instead of picture.

Comment: #pragma strict
private var guiShow : boolean = false;

var riddle : Texture;

function OnMouseDown () {

 guiShow = true;

}

function OnGUI()
{

 if(guiShow == true)
   {
    GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(Screen.width / 4.5, Screen.height / 4, 1024, 512), riddle);
   }



}

Comment: @DanielDixon Post your code in question, not as comment.

Comment: sorry there you go