# UI not blocking touches in Tango/Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

we are building an similar to the "Kitten - Placing Virtual objects in AR" example as shown here:

https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-placing-objects.

Basically when you touch the screen, a kitten appears on the real world plane (floor).

In our app we have a side menu, with a few buttons each showing a different game object.  Unfortunately when we touch one of these buttons, the selected object Instantiates behind the button on the screen.  We want the UI to block touches in Tango, and only allow touches to instantiate gameobjects on areas of the screen without UI elements.

I can't find any Tango examples which has touch and UI combined.  I've tried an asset called LeanTouch to block touches behind UI elements but it doesn't seem to work with Tango specifically.  Please help!

Edit:  I have tried using method 5 from this:

[How to detect events on UI and GameObjects with the new EventSystem API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api)

and while it does add a PhysicsRaycaster to the TangoARCamera (which is tagged as MainCamera), the OnPointerDown method produces no debug logs no matter where you touch the screen. Tango is a special case so this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: You have to change the way you detect touch on the 3D objects. On the duplicated answer use ***5**.For 3D Object (Mesh Renderer/any 3D Collider)*. Always a good a idea to post your code so that you won't get a solution with the exact code you have. It happens a-lot here.

Comment: Hi @Programmer, it doesn't work.  While it does add a PhysicsRaycaster to the TangoARCamera (which is tagged as MainCamera), the OnPointerDown method produces no debug messages no matter where you click on the screen.  I implemented 5. as described.  Can you please unmark this as duplicate as Tango is a special case