# How can I Completely Destroy or Finish Scene in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using OnGUI function and creating Buttons in scene. And one button triggers open old scene with this code:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene (3);
```

But when the new scene opens, the buttons is still shown. How can i prevent it ?

Comment: I am not using this :/

Answer (score 7):

> I am using OnGUI function and creating Buttons in scene.

I think that sums up your problem. I assume the script below is similar to how you are creating the Buttons.

```
public Texture btnTexture;
void OnGUI()
{
    if (!btnTexture)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector")
        return;
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 50, 50), btnTexture))
        Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 70, 50, 30), "Click"))
        Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

}
```

The `OnGUI` function will always create Buttons or UI controls inside its function every frame. It does not get destroyed when new scene is loaded as long as it is attached to a GameObject.

When your new scene is loaded, check if that script is attached to a GameObject. I assume it is. If it is, it will always execute the code inside it.

---

Do not use the `OnGUI` function in Unity. Start using Unity's new UI System. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) is a Unity official tutorial to get you started on that. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api/41392130#41392130) post for how to detect clicks on the new UI system from code.

Comment: @NurullahCelik You are welcome! Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your understand why that's happening