# Unity Collider Button is not working on Android

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, unityscript, collider

I have a problem with a collider button: when I use the button on PC it works fine, but when I use it on mobile device the script is not working (but the collider should make a fade effect).

[Video showing desired effect](https://youtu.be/JaaykOI7d4g).

This is the script I have:

```js
#pragma strict

function OnMouseDown(){
    GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent(orbit).mainMenu = false;  
    for (var child : Transform in GameObject.Find("logo").transform) {
        child.gameObject.active = false;    
    }
    var enemy:GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
    for (var child3 : GameObject in enemy) {
        Destroy(child3);
    }

    for (var child : Transform in GameObject.Find("menu_main").transform) {
        child.gameObject.active = false;    
    }   

    var num:GameObject[] = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("num");
    for (var child2 : GameObject in num) {
        Destroy(child2);
    }

    for (var child : Transform in GameObject.Find("menu_end").transform) {
        child.gameObject.active = false;    
    }   

    for (var child : Transform in GameObject.Find("healthbar").transform) {
        child.gameObject.active = true; 
    }   
    GameObject.Find("_Game").GetComponent(game).score = 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue boils down to something very simple.  While touch events are *similar* to mouse events and in a lot of ways they are handled the same, but this is one of those cases where they're not.

Simply put, [`OnMouseDown` doesn't work on mobile](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/124198/onmousedown-alternative-for-mobile.html).

The answer there has an outdated link (and contains a typo), here's where it should point:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/OnMouseDown

And the relevant code (in JS / UnityScript, which you are using, although I do advise switching to C#, it's relatively painless):

```
function Update () {
    // Code for OnMouseDown in the iPhone. Unquote to test.
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        // Construct a ray from the current touch coordinates
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray,hit)) {
            hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage("OnMouseDown");
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Just attach a new script with this function in it to the main camera and you're good to go. Your existing OnMouseDown script will start working again.

Comment: Switching from JS to C# is easy: you're already using `#Pragma strict` so all you'd have to do is change `var xxx : Type` to `Type xxx` and your for-loops to use `in` instead of a `:`

Comment: thank you for script an explanation , ur a life saver :*

Comment: @AndreMatiun Don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as accepted (the green checkmark). :)

Comment: OP's rep is not much to up-vote but can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer  and should if problem is solved.  Note that there are few places where `Physics.Raycast` should be used these days to detect clicks on objects otherwise OP will run into problems of clicks going through  UI and clicking on GameObjects. The new [`EventSystem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314) should be used for Unity 4.5 and above.