# How to detect scrolling up or down in panel for Unity3d?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollrect

I would like detect scrolling up or down. Should be like Windows Form below.

```
private void dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue > e.NewValue)
        {
            // here up
        }
        else
        {
            // here down
        }
    }
```

How to detect scrolling up or down in panel for Unity3d ?

```
public void OnScrollValueChanged(float value)
{
        if (?)
        {
            // here up
        }
        else
        {
            // here down
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `onValueChanged` for [`Scrollbar`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Scrollbar.html) and [`ScrollRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.html). Don't know which one you are using but here is a sample code to register to the `onValueChanged`  event. You can find other UI events examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects-with-the-new-eventsystem-api/41392130#41392130). Will modify it to include samples from this answer.

You likely need the `Scrollbar`. Get the original value, on start then compare it with the current value when scrolling. You can use that to determine up and down. This assumes that the [`direction`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Scrollbar-direction.html) is set to `TopToBottom`.

```
scrollBar.direction = Scrollbar.Direction.TopToBottom;
```

**Scrollbar:**

```
public Scrollbar scrollBar;
float lastValue = 0;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Subscribe to the Scrollbar event
    scrollBar.onValueChanged.AddListener(scrollbarCallBack);
    lastValue = scrollBar.value;
}

//Will be called when Scrollbar changes
void scrollbarCallBack(float value)
{
    if (lastValue > value)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Scrolling UP: " + value);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Scrolling DOWN: " + value);
    }
    lastValue = value;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Subscribe To Scrollbar Event
    scrollBar.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(scrollbarCallBack);
}
```

**ScrollRect:**

```
public ScrollRect scrollRect;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Subscribe to the ScrollRect event
    scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener(scrollRectCallBack);
}

//Will be called when ScrollRect changes
void scrollRectCallBack(Vector2 value)
{
    Debug.Log("ScrollRect Changed: " + value);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Subscribe To ScrollRect Event
    scrollRect.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(scrollRectCallBack);
}
```

Comment: This or if you want to do it like in the post, you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect-normalizedPosition.html but basically you would be rewriting what the onValueChanged does.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you!

Comment: This doesn't work because I have the scroll bar automatically gradually scroll down if new text appeared, but I want it to stop if the user clicked on scroll bar or scrolled inside. Then OnValueChanged will trigger in either case. I want something that only triggers on the user input, not the automatic scrolling