# Change Source Image of a UI Button when a mouse is over it? (Unity)

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Hello I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make a UI button change its Source Image when the mouse is over it, and when the mouse is no longer over the button, the button's Source Image is back to normal. I know that a sprite is needed to be the button's source image, so I created two image sprite files (one being the normal image and the other being the light-up image when the mouse hovers over the button)

Now here is a screenshot of the play button having its normal source image

[image]

Button will change its source image by lighting up when mouse goes over it

[image]

How do I do this task in C#? How do I change the source image of the button in C# when the mouse hovers over it?

This is what I got so far after looking at some references. I'm new to Unity so sorry for my lack of knowledge

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayButton : MonoBehaviour {

    private PlayButton pb;
    private Sprite newSprite;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        pb = GetComponentInChildren<PlayButton> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void onClick(){

    }

    public void onPointerHover(PointerEventData eventData){
        //When mouse hovers over the button, the button changes
        pb.image.overrideSprite = newSprite;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Button default behaviour already lights up the image when highlighted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as `onPointerHover`. To detect mouse over use `OnPointerEnter`. To detect when the mouse exist from the mouse over, use `OnPointerExit`. You have to implement `IPointerExitHandler` and `IPointerEnterHandler` in order to use these functions.

You read more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/3785314).

As for changing the source Image of the Button, `Button.image.sprite` or `Button.image.overrideSprite` can be used to do that.

Just attach this the Button Object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    private Button pb;
    public Sprite newSprite;

    void Start()
    {
        pb = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pb.image.sprite = newSprite; ;
        Debug.Log("Mouse Enter");
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse Exit");
        //Change Image back to default?
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Note that you don't have to do this yourself. Unity has built in way to do it.

**1**.Change the Button's Transition option from *"Color Tint"* to *"Sprite Swap"*.

**2**.Change the *"Highlighted Sprite"* slot to which ever Sprite you want.

[image]