# unity run a function as long a button is pressed in the inspector

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I'm a newbie in Unity

Using Unity Inspector i have setup a button that makes a callback to a function (OnClick), it works fine but only once, to fire the action again i need to release and click the button again

How can i make that the function keeps running over and over as long as the button is pressed? (like a machine gun)

```
public void MoveLeft ( )
{
    transform.RotateAround(Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up, -rotation / 4 * Time.deltaTime);
    infopanel.RotateAround(Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up, -rotation / 4 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Regards...

Comment: Did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnClick` can't do this. Use `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp`. Set a boolean variable to true/false in these function respectively then check that boolean variable in the `Update` function

Attach to the UI Button object:

```
public class UIPresser : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,
    IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool pressed = false;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (pressed)
            MoveLeft();
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up, -rotation / 4 * Time.deltaTime);
        infopanel.RotateAround(Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up, -rotation / 4 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

You can find other event functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130).