# Detect when multiple buttons are pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope my question is not duplicate.
I have two buttons.
I want to do an operation after two buttons are clicked on the page . The time the buttons are pressed may be different.
Please help me with an example.

Comment: Create two bools. Each enabled by one of the buttons. If two bools are true. Do your operation.

Comment: The title makes it a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708) but I will change it to reflect pressing two buttons. Look at the #2 from the link I provided above then use EmreE's suggestion to get what you want

Comment: Register your buttons to an observable list, and subscribe the class which must monitor the clicks to the observable.

Comment: @EmreE ok.....but i would run a method .......where i check  tow bool variable is true.

Comment: Do you know how to use UI Buttons OnClick method? If not [Check Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYzdhiRiKd0) a video from youtube. Shows how to assign scripts to buttons.

Comment: @EmreE Yes ..... but should not have a supervisory process like coroutine the one that is running and wait until the buttons are clicked ......please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a simple boolean variable for each button you set to true when the button is pressed. You can then check if both boolean variable are true in the `Update` function.

Attach to an empty GameObject and drag both buttons to the slots:

```
public Button button1;
public Button button2;

bool button1Pressed = false;
bool button2Pressed = false;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Register Button Events
    button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
    button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));

}

private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
{
    if (buttonPressed == button1)
    {
        //Your code for button 1
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button1.name);
        button1Pressed = true;
    }

    if (buttonPressed == button2)
    {
        //Your code for button 2
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + button2.name);
        button2Pressed = true;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //Check if both buttons have been pressed
    if (button1Pressed && button2Pressed)
    {
        //Do something
        Debug.Log("BOTH BUTTONS HAVE BEEN PRESSED");

        //Set both to false
        button1Pressed = false;
        button2Pressed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah yeah.......i like you brother

Comment: Thank EmreE as his/her first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465197/detect-when-multiple-buttons-are-pressed/46465685#comment79885267_46465197) is actually what I put as an answer after I noticed you are still struggling to do this. Happy coding!