# No dynamic float visible for attachment in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, particles

I am trying attach a particle system's gravity modifier with a slider but it is not visible. Here is a screen shot of what I see.

[image]

Should I give this up and try to attach the value using a script instead ? ? ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see it from the Editor because `main.gravityModifier` is a type of `MinMaxCurve` not `float` so you **cannot** assign the `Slider` value which is `float` to it from the Editor. There is a function that let's you do that from scripting. That's why it works from script.

Do that from code. It looks like you already got an answer but there are so many things to improve.

**1**.Don't use `GameObject.Find` every frame.

You are currently doing this 2 times in a frame with `GameObject.Find("Slider")` and `GameObject.Find("Particle System")`. Cache the `Slider` and the `ParticleSystem` components. Move those functions to the `Start` or `Awake` function.

**2**.Do not use the `Slider` value to modify `main.gravityModifier` every
   frame.

Use the [`onValueChanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130) event to subscribe to the `Slider` so that you will only modify `main.gravityModifier` when the slider value changes. The `Update` function is no longer needed when you do this.

```
private ParticleSystem ps;
public Slider slider;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Cache the Slider and the ParticleSystem variables
    slider = GameObject.Find("Slider").GetComponent<Slider>();
    ps = GameObject.Find("Particle System").GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}

void OnEnable()
{
    //Subscribe to the Slider Click event
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { sliderCallBack(slider.value); });
}

//Will be called when Slider changes
void sliderCallBack(float value)
{
    Debug.Log("Slider Changed: " + value);

    var main = ps.main;
    main.gravityModifier = value;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Subscribe To Slider Event
    slider.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Just as a side-note, I would not use `GameObject.Find` unless the objects have truly unique names, to avoid messing up which object you retrieve.

Comment: Yes. If you have multiple objects with the-same name but under different objects then use the "/" to access them like "parentname/childname". Just don't have multiple **root** object with the-same name.

Comment: Thank you! This is highly useful.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept answer if you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

I got the scripting answer, but if any of you has a better solution you are welcome to share it.

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class SliderScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private double sf;
    private ParticleSystem ps;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        sf = GameObject.Find("Slider").GetComponent<Slider>().value;
        ps = GameObject.Find("Particle System").GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        var main = ps.main;
        main.gravityModifier = (float)sf;
        print(sf );
    }
}
```