# How to Show scrollable panel in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to show a ui panel using unity3d ,I have a main camera scene after i click a button ,i want my scrollable panel to show up

just like this

[image]

after i click the menu button i want the scrolling ui to appear like this.
[image]

It'd be great if someone could point out some kind of a tutorial that would cover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following:

- [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) component - This is used to represent the items you want
  to display
- [`Grid Layout Group`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html) component - This is used to arrange those
  image components you want to display.
- [`Content Size Fitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html) component  - This is used to make sure
  that those Images fit in the Grid Layout.

The video from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyIo5tlNNeA) should show you how to use these 3 together to get what you are looking for. To detect which `Image` is clicked, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130) post.