# Detects which collider is typed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have an object hit that contains a Polygon Collider, and in this object I have some objects that contain BoxCollider. Now I'm trying to detect when I click Polygon Collider, and when I click Box Collider. So when I click Box Collider, you should avoid the Polygon Collider.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))

       if (hit.collider.GetType() != typeof(BoxCollider2D))
       {
            Debug.Log("Bad Click");
       }
       else
            Debug.Log("Good Click");
}
```

So I can not find any way to help me. If anyone has any idea, thank you!!!

Comment: so when you click the Box collider the collision is detected for both box and the polygon?

Comment: yes....but I would like to initially detect the  box collider , and if it is to avoid the polygon collider

Comment: so in your code, you just can say if both of them got detected then only call the method for when only the box collider is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't  work at-all because `RaycastHit` and `Physics.Raycast` are used for 3D colliders. For 2D colliders, `RaycastHit2D` and `Physics2D.Raycast` should be used. Also, for checking if the object has `BoxCollider2D` or `PolygonCollider2D` attached to it, the `GetComponent` function is used instead of `hit.collider.GetType()`. It returns `null` when the component is not available.

Your raycast code should look like something below:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Camera cam = Camera.main;

    Vector2 wPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(wPoint, Vector2.zero);

    //Check if we hit anything
    if (hit)
    {
        if (hit.collider.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>() != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Bad Click");
        }
        else if (hit.collider.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>() != null)
            Debug.Log("Good Click");
    }
}
```

---

That should fix your problem but I suggest you use the new Event System with `OnPointerClick`. See **#7** from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects/41392130#41392130) answer on how to use it with a 2D collider.

Comment: yes, it works, but it has bugs, many times when need to debug good click, I get a bad click

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the position of z. We have changed to objects containing the Box Collider 2D Z position ahead.