# Several Issues with IPointerClickHandler Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a very simple button in Unity, using the information provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects) but after a multitude of attempts it won't seem to work.

I have a "button" object, with a `SpriteRenderer` and `BoxCollider2D` component, a `Physics2DRaycaster` attached to my main camera, and the following code attached to the object:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }  

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked" + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

This is the scene, there is clearly nothing obstructing the button:

[image]

There is only the button and the camera in the scene:

[image]

And these are the components attached to both the camera and the button:

[image]

[image]

I'm aware this isn't strictly the kind of question to ask on here but it's been several days now and this should have been something very simple but can not for the life of me see what's gone wrong.

Comment: @hellium even if my button is a gameObject?

Comment: With a sprite renderer

Comment: Read the troubleshooting part. If this is a sprite renderer then the object is 2D which means after attaching `Physics2DRaycaster` to the camera, you must attach any 2D collider to it. `CircleCollider2D` or `BoxCollider2D` should be fine. Also,  you don't need to put that Sprite under the canvas. If you have to then consider using the `Image` or `RawImage` component which doesn't require collider at-all.

Comment: @Programmer I've done all those things, I've updated the question to make it more clear

Comment: Ok. Can you also add screenshot of the Hierarchy tab?

Comment: @Programmer there’s one there

Comment: I see it now. That means you only have two objects in the scene? Camera and the object you want to detect clicks on?

Comment: @programmer yeah

Comment: Read the duplicate again.  Scroll down to the "Troubleshooting" section. Read part A. It says something about EventSystem and shows how to create that. You must do that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Image component added to your object? For the event to trigger you need to have a component that can be a RaycastTarget, ie, it won't trigger from an empty gameObject, it also needs to be child of Canvas.

If you start from fresh scene and create any UI element from the GameObject menu, Unity will create an Event System, Canvas and InputModule components, which is a great start - if you can click the button, you should get your debug if you click on an image with your script - your code is correct.

For a sprite working with the event system, you'll need a physics raycaster and collider. A 3D Box collider works with Physics Raycaster, and 2D Box Collider works with Physics2D Raycaster, but if no collider is present your sprite won't intercept raycasts, they need colliders to work

Comment: There is a sprite renderer attached and the object is a child of the canvas

Comment: sprite renderer is not meant for use with the UI system, use an Image or RawImage instead

Comment: for raycasts to work with sprites, use Physics Raycaster instead of Graphics Raycaster

Comment: It isn’t a UI object its just a gameObject that I want to be able to click

Comment: Dont make it a child of canvas then, and the camera needs to have a PhysicsRaycaster, not the graphics one, also, make sure the object has a collider (box collider is a good starting point)

Comment: The camera does have a PhysicsRaycaster

Comment: Add a Box Collider to your sprite then (Or box2D if you want to use physics2D raycaster)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that, almost forgot that sprites don't have colliders by default

Comment: Okay so with the object, a boxcollider and a physics2draycaster I should be able to just use the code I’ve got in my question?