# Detecting pressed button in UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton, detection

I'm starting with Unity 3D, and I'm trying to move player when a UI (not on keyboard) button is pressed down.
But I cant work it out and i have done a lot of research.

Comment: make use of `EventSystem` : https://stackoverflow.com/q/41391708/366064

Comment: It looks more like you need visual joystick than just a UI button. EventSystem can be use to implement visual joystick. See the two duplicate links

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for non complex tasks and without coding for the Button (works only if button and the Script for moving in the scene):

- Select the button in the scene
- On the Button component in the inspector you have a box ***OnClick()*** with a ***+***
- By pressing the plus you add a new field for a listner to react on the click
- This gameobject has to hold your move script
- After **selecting** the **gamobject**:

  - in the right **drop down select** your **script** for the movement on the gameobject and **then choose the method** for movement