# How to detect click events on mesh built from VertexHelper?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I used the example provided by Unity (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) to create a new visual UI component.

However, I now want to detect a click event on the newly created mesh. To do so I implemented the IPointerClickHandler interface but the click is detected when I click within the RectTransform box of the GameObject but not on the actual Mesh (which is outside of the RectTransform).

Screenshot (mesh in pink):
[image: Screenshot (mesh in pink)]

I tried the solutions suggested here for "NON-UI OBJECTS" https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/9989790 but with no success.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "MeshCollider" component on the object.  In addition, your camera needs to have a "physics raycaster" component.  The ray is cast out from the camera, and if it collides with your mesh-collider, pointer-enter/exit (and potential-click) events will be sent to your object.

But even with these required components in place, you'll still need to watch out for overlapping objects that might "steal" the mouse click.