# Get the field name from the parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I get the field name from the parameter? I would like to call the method like `CompareValues("points");`

```
public void CompareValues(string field)
    {
    int value = Card.GetComponent<CardScript>().field;
```

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have about 10+ fields (Card game). Now I have to create multiple methods to get the values. I would like to have one method and pass an argument what field I would like to get.

Comment: Alright. So, how do those methods get the name of the field to display?

Comment: Thanks, button click. For every field there is a button also.

Comment: Instead of using reflection, I would instead recommend to [bind listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392130/1092820) to the buttons. and then make `CompareValues` take getter and setter delegates as parameters, and use those inside of `CompareValues`. For instance, `public void CompareValues(Func<int> getter, Action<int> setter){ int value = getter();}` then when binding the liseners, create the getters & setters: `button1.onClick.AddListener(() => CompareValues(()=>Card.GetComponent<CardScript>().field, (int inValue) => Card.GetComponent<CardScript>().field = inValue));`

Comment: Thanks - I need to dive into this. So many new concepts for me :)